# CSS nth with image

Tags: css

I have a slideshow that is imported with a shortcode in WP.

I'm trying to add custom css to each 4th image that is displayed, but with no luck.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

```
.thumb-res .ngg-gallery-thumbnail:nth-child(4) img { border: 1px solid #000 !important; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb-res">
<div class="ngg-galleryoverview" id="ngg-gallery-97131261c1bb7b3c15f04e8ef0f97c77-1">
<div class="slideshowlink">
  <a href='url'>[Show as slideshow]</a>
</div>
<div id="ngg-image-0" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
  <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
    <a href="url" title=" " data-image-id='48' class="ngg-fancybox" rel="97131261c1bb7b3c15f04e8ef0f97c77">
      <img title="slide4" alt="slide4" src="url" width="174" height="150" style="max-width:none;"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ngg-image-1" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
  <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
    <a href="url" title=" " data-image-id='46' class="ngg-fancybox" rel="97131261c1bb7b3c15f04e8ef0f97c77">
      <img title="slide2" alt="slide2" src="url" width="174" height="150" style="max-width:none;"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this article: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ngg-gallery-thumbnail` elements are all single children of their respective parents, so the selector never selects anything. You should select based on elements with the class `ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box`, which are all siblings:

```
.thumb-res .ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box:nth-child(4) img { ... }
```

That said, this is still not going to work exactly as expected because it looks like there are also siblings that are not thumbnail boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(".thumb-res .ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box:nth-child(4n+1)").addClass("fourth");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/QMXg3/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.thumb-res .ngg-gallery-thumbnail-**box**:nth-child(**4n**) img { 
    border: 1px solid #000 !important; 
}
```

with your code you're selecting just the 4th image. you need 4n for each 4th:D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nth-child(an+b) for direct siblings.

```
.thumb-res .ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box:nth-child(4n+1) img { border: 1px solid #000 !important; }
```

Also for add custom css to **each** 4th image that is displayed you need to use argument in format of "an+b".
For example 4n+1 select 4th, 8th, 12th element etc.